# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cx_Oracle)

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I compiled python3.8 on a half dozen servers (SUSE Linux) and it is working fine on most of them.

But on one, it throws this weird error when I try to install and use the cx_Oracle library.

I set up a virtual environment, and pip install cx_Oracle (version 8.0.0).  The installation works fine, but then when I try to import cx_Oracle, it throws an error:

```
[GCC 4.8.5] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cx_Oracle)
>>>
```

Not sure what to look for here.  Any thoughts on what the problem might be, or how to trace this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed!  It turned out there was a PYTHONPATH environment variable active that was pointing to the old Python 2.7 folders, even though I was in a Python 3.8 virtual environment.  After deleting that environment variable, it started working.

More info with how we diagnosed it here:
https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/464