# Can not import subprocess in python3

Tags: python-3.x, import, subprocess

I can not import subprocess in python3. I prepare a simply text.py with "import subprocess", and python3 text.py, it promotes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text.py", line 1, in <module>
    import re, subprocess
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__posixsubprocess)
```

what's the problem? and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: my code is only two words:  import subprocess

Comment: You might want to check on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63003247/10895906